# Searching/sorting and string encoding in Java

Tags: java, sorting, search, character-encoding

I'm building a small in-memory file system in Java for a project, I'm currently using a binary search to locate nodes but when I was looking for bugs I noticed that nodes with capitals would be sorted to the beginning of the list because of their position in Unicode. This still works fine for finding nodes with binary search but while they should represent an alphabetically sorted list this is not acceptable, for example:

```
Hosts.txt abc home settings.txt
```

What I'm thinking would be the easiest solution (theoretically) would be to have the strings in a charset with the characters laid out something like this:

```
aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmM... and so on with special characters and such included
```

Is there some way to do this easily or perhaps a better way?

Comment: How do you sort the Strings?

Comment: I have used binary search to find a position to insert into a list. However it's part of the problem as the difference between 'A' and 'a' is the whole alphabet a binary search with Unicode strings would not work to order the list as requested

Comment: Some code would definitely help, but you should probably compare the strings in the binary search as case-insensitive

Comment: I don't see how any code would help. But using case-insensitive comparisons in the binary search would make "Hosts.txt" and "hosts.txt" equal which is my whole point.

Comment: True, but you can decide what to do when two strings are equal in case-insensitive comparison . .

Comment: But it would mean two iterations, one towards the beginning of the list and another towards the end as to find it's right place among the case-insensitive strings that equals the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your own comparator:

```
public class MyStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

        int caseIgnoreResult = s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        if (caseIgnoreResult == 0) {
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
        else {
            return caseIgnoreResult;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But I need it to be case-sensitive as otherwise "aB" and "Ab" would be considered the same, which would break my binary search.

Comment: If compareToIgnoreCase returns 0 (the strings are equal by ignoring case considerations), test the equality again with compareTo().

Comment: @Linuxxon I have edited my answers, hope it's what you are actually looking for.